# гит превышен лимит 100мб

Tags: git, github, git-push

пытаюсь запушить на гитхаб файл 130 мб, получаю такую ошибку:

> remote: error: File talk.mp4 is 130.99 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file
>   size limit of 100.00 MB

следущее что я делаю удаляю файл из репы. делаю еще пару комитов и теперь получается не могу запушить изменения. Каждый раз он как будто отправляет через сеть этот файл которого нет уже, и сообщает о вышеупомянутой ошибке.

результат git log на локальном пк:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно не файл удалить, а коммит с файлом. Когда вы удалили файл и закоммитили, то коммит с добавленным файлом остался и он был послан на гитхаб. Для удаления последнего коммита: `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, для удаления указанного коммита: `git reset --soft <sha1-commit-id>`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помогла команда из комментариев:

> git reset --soft "sha1-commit-id"

единственный момент, который для меня остался не ясным. Коммиты что были после добавления большого файла , после выполнения команды исчезли. Но изменения которые были в них вроде остались.

Comment: Ну да, эта команда именно тем и занимается, что удаляет все коммиты после указанного (а опция `--soft` сохраняет изменения)

Comment: @andreymal, она никакие коммиты не удаляет, просто меняет указатель HEAD.

Comment: @ixSci насколько я знаю, если на них никто больше не указывает, то однажды набежит сборщик мусора и они таки удалятся окончательно

Comment: @andreymal, это правда. Просто сама команда ничего не удаляет.

Comment: @andreymal@ixSci :господа, минуточку. то есть большая вероятность того что мои изменения пропадут. хотя сейчас они есть и представленны в виде нового компонента в коде.